# How to reduce bytes number in SOAP response?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

is there a way to reduce the number of bytes sent to the network from a SOAP response? I use nuSoap in PHP and would like to avoid xsi:type="xsd:string", xsi:type="xsd:int" in every node.
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance
c.

Comment: Can you switch from XML to JSON?  XML is wordy.  JSON (and YAML) are not as wordy.  Can you switch?

Comment: I cannot :-) Response are read from Flash and who develops Flash app only knows XML but he does not want verbose output

Comment: @S.Lott: the problem is more the fact that he's using PHP and nuSOAP, which tend to pass everything as primitive types: no schemas. That requires the type to be output for each element.

Comment: @John Saunders: What?  Define all the schema you want, each element still has verbose type information.  They just aren't primitive types.

Comment: @S.Lott: I don't know what kind of service you're used to, but mine don't have type information on every element.

Comment: @John Saunders: All XML I've ever seen has tags which are -- in effect -- type information.  Are you suggesting that some services don't use tags?

Comment: @S.Lott: the OP has `<Request><Param1 xsi:type='xs:int'>1</Param1><Param2 xsi:type='xs:string'>abc</Param2></Request>`. I'm talking about `<Request><Param1>1</Param1><Param2>abc</Param2></Request>`. The type information is in the schema and need not be present on every message.

Comment: @John Saunders: I fail to see how `<Param1>` is not -- essentially -- the data type of `1`.  You're saying that it's not the type, it's something else?  What is it if it's not the data type?

Comment: @S.Lott: `<Param1>` is the element that the value `1` happens to reside in. The schema is what tells you the type of the value `1`. That's in contrast to `<Param1 xsi:type='xs:int'>1</Param1>` where the `xsi:type` tells you the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are strictly tied to sending valid SOAP response back to Flash client, and if using valid schema is not an option (which would simplify output markup), then **no, you can't do anything about it**...

However, if you're NOT tied to sending valid SOAP response, and your developer *really* insists on getting non-verbose markup, then you are left with an alternative of rolling your own. If this is the case, read on.

You can use some of existing XML Serializer classes available via [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/), or [some other source](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2986-PHP-Store-and-retrieve-objects-from-XML-document.html). If you wanted to go down the Trully-Roll-Your-Own route, there are [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) [classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to aid you in creating valid XML directly.

Not to repeat what's being said elsewhere, [here's in-depth example about how to serialize some data using PEAR XML_Serializer](http://www.devshed.com/index2.php?option=content&task=view&id=410&pop=1&hide_ads=1&page=0&hide_js=1).

Another *really simple* example, this time it's SimpleXML-based, where you add child elements and attributes as needed to meet desired output.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>');
$ch1 = $xml->addChild("root");
$ch2 = $ch1->addChild("element");
// you obviously have no use for attributes, but I included it for completeness
$ch2->addAttribute("foo", "bar");
$ch2->addChild("subElement", "value1");

$outxml = $xml->asXML();
```

Code above would produce something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <element foo="bar">
         <subElement>value1</subElement>
    </element>
</root>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to enable compression in the HTTP layer. If you want to make sure that you're always compressing data, you could even reject SOAP requests that are not compressed. (A [popular software Q&A site](http://stackoverflow.com) does this.)

Comment: the problem is that who reads xml does not want "useless" tags: if i enable compression i do not avoid this, is right? 

I would need to send simple structures like 

<TAG1><TAG2>123</TAG2></TAG1>  

instead of <SOAP:bla><TAG1 xsi:type="xsd:string"><TAG2 xsi:type="xsd:string">123</TAG2></TAG1></SOAP:bla>

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespaces and gzip the contents during transport.

```
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
$xml=new DOMDocument($soap);
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace(FALSE);
echo $xml->saveXML();
```